# Is returning a List<T> from a property allocating memory in c#

Tags: c#, .net

What happens if I define something like

```
private List<ObjData> _listObjs = new List<ObjData>();
public List<ObjData> ListObjs
{
   get { return _listObjs; }
}
```

and in code I add simply to the ListObj?

```
ListObjs.add(element);
```

did I get a waste of memory?

Comment: What do you mean with "waste of memory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `List<T>` is a reference type. By returning a reference type in a property etc, you are only sharing a post-it-note *per se* (a memory address), not recreating or copying memory (apart from the reference itself, which is stack allocated...)

So the answer is, yes a very small amount of extra memory is allocated on the stack and will be reclaimed as soon as that reference falls out of scope, but you are not heap allocating or copying the whole list again.

In short, you shouldn't worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you return an internal list in a getter, it can be manipulated from outside your class. So yes, you can add to the ListObj like that, and no, you are not wasting memory, because you are not returning a copy of the list in the getter.